# Azure data factory job failing with Job Completed Batch error code

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data factory pipeline activity is failing with the error "The specified job is already in a completed state.". Even re-running the activity is also failing with same error.

There are no stderr.txt and stdout.txt files generated for the tasks to gain additional insight into the issue.

```
"statusCode": 409,
    "statusMessage": "The specified job is already in a completed state.",
    "batchErrorCode": "JobCompleted",
    "batchErrorMessage": "The specified job is already in a completed state."
```

Can anyone help us how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which activity is giving this error. Could you please share the screenshot and more relevant information around what you are trying to achieve using the pipeline?

Comment: the issue has been resolved as the job in batch account is in completed state instead of active. We made to active and worked.